# ReactNativeDisplay Json file in another format

Tags: json, react-native

rookie in RN, thanks in advance! I want to display a json file on a page.

This is the format of the json:

```
{
  "prediction": [
            { "name":"egg", "value":"0.95" },
            { "name":"apple", "value":"0.02" },
            { "name":"peach", "value":"0.01" },
            { "name":"orange", "value":"0.01" },
            { "name":"fish", "value":"0.01" }

  ]
}
```

Assuming the Name of the json will be " /app/prediction.json ".
And the text input method I had on this page will be :

```
import { Tile, List, ListItem, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  View
} from 'react-native';


export default class ProjectOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

       <Text style={styles.text}> Analysis </Text>
       <Text> The object has " 95% possibility to be an egg, 40% to be an apple "</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  container: {
    height: 275,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  preview: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'flex-end',
   alignItems: 'center',
   height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
   width: Dimensions.get('window').width
 },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: '#ffffff',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 40
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ProjectOne', () => ProjectOne);
```

Is there any way that I can fetch the json file, and then, display the json content into that text field on this page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `require('./app/prediction.json')` then convert it to string or format if needed